# Aligning TextBlock Vertically Inside StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application I have a `DataGrid` with multiple `DataGridTemplateColumns`. One of the columns looks like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeSource}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>    
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>           
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" CornerRadius="6" BorderThickness="2">
                            <StackPanel Background="Green" Width="200" Height="150">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="17" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>           
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

As you can see the `TextBlock` which displays the `Title` is not vertically centered inside the green `StackPanel`. How can I do that?

Comment: Remove the StackPanel. It's completely unneeded and it will not allow you to vertically center the text.

Comment: Remove which stackpanel?

Comment: `<StackPanel Background="Green" Width="200" Height="150">` - Remove that.

Comment: Remove StackPanel, and use Grid and set size of TextBlock.

Answer (score 2):

`StackPanel` doesn't have a concept of its height, so you can't vertically-align its children.  You'll have to do something a bit differently.

For example, move the fixed 150-height and background from the StackPanel to its parent border -- that way, you can vertically-align the StackPanel within the Border:

```
<Border Background="Green" Height="150" BorderBrush="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" CornerRadius="6" BorderThickness="2">
    <StackPanel Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="17" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

(It's not really clear why you're using that inner StackPanel since it only has one child, but I've assumed you're going to add something else to it.)